# How can I get notifications to my phone when an exception occurs on my java server?

Tags: java, server, push-notification, devops, monitoring

I run a java application on a server at home and want to be notified on my Android phone when an exception occurs so that I can fix it.

I loose money if it stops running.

I could send an email, or even a text from my java application but I want something specific. I don't want to have to reach for my phone every time I get an email or text.

Is there some Android client app that works with a monitoring API on my server? I can't find anything suitable on Playstore.

What I want is a server API,  preferably Java, that will send a message to a phone app that pops up a notification on the phone. The API doesn't have to be Java: Rust,C,Python, anything easy on Linux.

Comment: Have you tried a specialized software forvthat purpose like PagerDuty?

Comment: Thanks,  looks good but I just tried to sign up for their free service for up to 5 users and it said,  "Trials work best with a business email address".

Answer (score 0):

Open a new email account just for server exceptions. Install a new email client on my phone just for this account.  Turn on notifications so it makes a noise when an email is sent.  Then, when an exception occurs on the server,
send an email to the new email address.